# Inserting a new div between two grid items

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following grid layout:

```
<div class="main-page">
  <div class="side-bar"></div>
  <div class="nav-bar"></div>
  <div class="index-view"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

and I am trying to insert a new div between sidebar and index such that the resulting layout will be like:

```
<div class="main-page">
  <div class="side-bar"></div>
  <div class="nav-bar"></div>
  <div class="profile-pane"></div>
  <div class="index-view"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

My attempt so far has been:

```
.main-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 72px 1fr;
  height: 100%;
}

.main-page > .side-bar {
  display: grid;
  grid-row: 1/4;
  width: 80px;
}

.main-page > .profile-pane {
  width: 260px;
  position: relative;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.main-page > .index-view {
  grid-row: 2/4;
}
```

This renders a huge space between `profile` and `index` and compresses `index` to the right. I've been trying different values for the `grid-row` property but to no avail. However, if I remove either one of `profile` and `index`, the remaining div will render nicely and right beside the sidebar. How do I achieve the second layout?

Comment: You **obviously** need to adjust your grid-template-columns. You want to have three columns, but you defined only two. So what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider different values based on the existance of the `profile` element:

```css
.main-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 80px 1fr 4fr;
  grid-template-rows: 72px 1fr;
  height: 200px;
  margin:20px;
}

.side-bar {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.nav-bar,
.index-view {
 grid-column:span 2;
}

/* Take only one clumn if profile exist*/
.profile-pane + .index-view {
 grid-column:span 1;
}

/* Irrelevant code */

.main-page > * {
 border:1px solid;
}

.main-page > *:before {
  content:attr(class);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-page">
  <div class="side-bar"></div>
  <div class="nav-bar"></div>
  <!--<div class="profile-pane"></div>-->
  <div class="index-view"></div>
</div>

<div class="main-page">
  <div class="side-bar"></div>
  <div class="nav-bar"></div>
  <div class="profile-pane"></div>
  <div class="index-view"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result by setting the "grid-row: span 2" property in the sidebar to increase its height by two lines. And for the navigation bar, the "grid-column: span 2" property is to expand it into two columns

Oh yes, and do not forget to set the columns of the required width for the grid container `grid-template-columns: 10% 15% 70%;`

**Result:**

```css
.main-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 15% 70%;
}

.main-page>* {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.side-bar {
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.nav-bar {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.index-view {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-page">
  <div class="side-bar">side-bar</div>
  <div class="nav-bar">nav-bar</div>
  <div class="profile-pane">profile-pane</div>
  <div class="index-view">index-view</div>
</div>
```

[image]